# Is there a way to reduce time between Azure deployment start and role OnStart() code being invoked?

Tags: windows, deployment, azure

Currently when I create a deployment using Windows Azure Management Portal it takes about 9 (nine!) minutes to have the code in my role `OnStart()` being run. I feel something is wrong there - nine minutes is ridiculously long.

I have a small startup task that I expect to finish in few seconds (and it finishes in few seconds when run under Compute Emulator), so looks like the Azure infrastructure is *doing something big* in there all that time.

Is there a way to speed the process up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Windows Azure generally takes 5-15 minutes to deploy. What it's doing is spinning up servers, VMs, booting Windows, etc. It's getting faster over time, but nine minutes is certainly not out of the ordinary.

Comment: IMO that's ridiculous. Why isn't there a small fleet of servers readily available at all times? Windows 2008 boots in less than two minutes, so I perceive anything longer than that as being ridiculously slow.

Comment: Ridiculous is correct...I just waited in excess of 45 minutes for a SMALL instance to be provisioned.  Uhhh, how many servers does it need to 'spin up' to provision one instance?  Very disappointing.

Comment: If this wait time is interrupting you at all you are doing the dev lifecycle wrong for Azure. You should develop locally with or without emulator and push up to staging, leaving prod alive. None of that should prevent you from working.

Answer (score 13):

When you deploy an application to Windows Azure depend on your VM size and instance count this is what happens:

1. You provide VM Type (small, medium, large, ex-large) and instance count (ex. N)
2. Depend on VM type setting, if you have chosen small then Fabric Controller (FC) needs to find a slot where a single core VM can be started for you or if you chosen ex-large, then FC needs to find a host machine to host 8 cores guest VM. In this step, 2 possibilities could occur (there are more but for simplicity I am quoting 2 only):

   2.1  FC could find a ready node (or rack) which already have 1 or more core free to host your VM
   2.2  FC may not find any empty core(s) in all running Host nodes and for you a new nodes need to be restarted to host your guest VM
3. If your VM got selected for path 2.1, in that case the host VM is already ON and host machine just need to provision a guest VM for you depend on your size. This may take less time because the system just need to provision and start your VM only.
4. IF your VM got selected for path 2.2, in that case first the host machine will start (if it is not running and which is very common*) and then your guest VM needs to be provisioned and start. And this path will take longer then path 2.1.

Note: With 2.1 and 2.2, it is possible that you may have to separate experience when deploying the same application.

1. Same thing will happen to find N instances to run for your service, however this process will happen parallel to 2.1/2.2 but the timing will be pretty much same. Also FC also need to find different fault domains for each instance so in case one instance is down, the others are still active.

So inside the system there is a lot going on than simply turning a Windows Server 2008 machine on. Because multiple VM are running on one single host security is primary so when a guest VM is provisioned, lots of things are done to keep things work in order.

About your comment on "small fleet of servers readily available at all times", that is good comment but when there a data center serving to whole world "Small" is very "huge" number and just to keep thousands of machine running without any guest is not logical. Also you just deploy once in a while, this is not what you will do on daily basis so having under 10 minutes is still comprehensible.

Comment: yes, but when you use their auto-scale mechanism it takes same amount of time to get new instance ready. and in case you need more instances due to system load - 10 minutes might be a long time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to existing VMs in Azure that you stop (deallocate) and start once in a while, then yes - there is a way to make it super fast, but you pay for it.
You have to move your VMs to use premium storage.

Main difference is, premium storage is not only on much faster SSD drives, but it does not get archived when not in use - so you pay for it even while you VM is offline.
See, normal stoage VM, when you start it they copy to VHD into another storage where it runs from, when you are done it is archived and you do not pay for that disk.

But with premium storage your VHD always stay ready to run, so when you start your VM it is not copied anywhere. this makes it much faster. Downside: you pay for the VHD even when the VM is deallocated.

So, up to you if you want to pay that or not - but there is a way to do it.

(I am not an azure specialist but I did ask a few fellow MVPs about it and that's what they explained. Would love to hear if this is not accurate).

Comment: Is this for IaaS VMs only?