# What takes so long between Azure startup task exiting and OnStart() being run?

Tags: windows, deployment, azure

My Azure web role includes a startup task written as a .cmd file and an overridden `OnStart()`. I log every startup step I can together with UTC timestamps. The last statement of the .cmd file is like this:

```
 echo startup task exiting >"%~dp0\Exiting.log"
```

and in `OnStart()` I retrieve the `Exiting.log" file and its creation and modification timestamps and log them all.

Turns out that 14 seconds pass between the file last modification timestamp and the `OnStart()` invokation. This adds up to the [overall very long startup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10546624/57428).

What's happening in between? Can I reduce that time?

Comment: You're trying to shave 14 seconds off of a 9-minute process? If it's a web role, it could be IIS config. \*shrug\*

Comment: @smarx: I think of it this way: maybe 9 minutes turn into 2 minutes at some moment and then these 14 seconds won't seem so irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Steve pointed out, starting IIS takes time. 
In addition, configuring plug-ins, such as diagnostics monitor and Connect, also takes time. In general, it is expected to see some delay between startup tasks and OnStart.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: This doesn't seem to make much sense - the role won't accept incoming requests until `OnStart()` returns `true`, so starting and configuring IIS can be done in parallel with `OnStart()`.

Comment: If we run the deployment in Compute Emulator, we’ll see more details. Before OnStart is invoked, diagnostics monitor will be started (otherwise we won’t be able to log anything in OnStart). While Compute Emulator is not identical to the cloud environment, it is very close.

Comment: If Diagnostics Monitor needs 14 seconds to start that's not acceptable - too slow.