# Azure/SSL works in staging kills roles in production

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ssl, azure

I generated a self-signed cert, exported and uploaded to the subscription. When I deploy to staging, all works well when I navigate to the app (MVC) it redirects to https appropriately, I get the warning but all works perfect when I continue to the site. When I deploy same package to production, none of my roles responds, to web requests or tcp, I can't even RDP into the VMs.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I'm going to say this is closed. I gave it an hour (watched tv to clear my head).. and it started functioning correctly. Perhaps it just took an extra long time to spin up the VMs.

Comment: possibly port blocks by firewall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time it take longer then expected for the role to start and if you are interested to know why I have explained in the following SO question:

[Is there a way to reduce time between Azure deployment start and role OnStart() code being invoked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546624/is-there-a-way-to-reduce-time-between-azure-deployment-start-and-role-onstart/10555557#10555557)

Want to know more let me know and I would love to explain in much finer details.