# Deploying Windows Azure, DNS name not working

Tags: azure, dns, subscription

I have two free subscriptions for windows azure and because I exceeded the limit on the first one, Microsoft closed it down. So I tried to deploy my application from the other subscription, and changed a few settings, and it seems to take a lot longer and the dns name of the depolyed application (in production area) does not seem to work. (I've been waiting for about 15 minutes.. in the other subscription it was almost immediate that the link started to work..). Also my webrole seems to be in a state of busy for  a very long time..

The application always worked fine and now I'm getting all this trouble just by switching subscription?? I'm getting really frustrated with this especially because I all worked perfectly before. Now I have to 'waste' my time getting all the things to work again and I can't start with anything new. I don't think this is normal but I can't seem to find the solution to this either.

edit:
Over half an hour the dns finally started working but this still does not fix the problem with the extreme slow deploying and the busy state of the webrole..

Comment: I take it you did redeploy from your Development environment of your Azure code base? Did you have a CName mapping to your old Web Site on Azure? Can't see any outages mentioned: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/service-dashboard/ Are your Web Roles active now, I assume they are as you can hit the DNS and see your site?

Comment: Yes I did, I did not have a CName mapping and they are active now .. i'm just happy it works but extremly slow for the small application I made..

Comment: Could you restate the question more clearly? I couldn't quite understand what you're asking. If you want to know if Azure sometimes takes more than 15 minutes to deploy a new hosted service, in my experience it can take 20-30 minutes.

Comment: I think you're confusing two different delays. The time to actually get the app up and running is typically 10-30 minutes, see Akvash's answer for more. When you start a new Hosted Service (or delete the Production deployment and start it up again) you get a new IP address. That takes an unpredictable amount of time (typically 30-90 minutes, in my experience) to propagate through the DNS system. But as long as you keep that Production deployment running, it won't happen again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please study the discussion below to understand why the time to deploy an application could vary between 10-30 minutes:

[Is there a way to reduce time between Azure deployment start and role OnStart() code being invoked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546624/is-there-a-way-to-reduce-time-between-azure-deployment-start-and-role-onstart/10555557#10555557)

Above details will helped you to get the answer about your statement ".. this still does not fix the problem with the extreme slow deploying and the busy state of the webrole.."..

To add more about that, when your application is deployment phase it goes through several state and in some cases the time taken in one state could be longer then expected and during this time you will see status as "Busy", "Initializing", "Starting.." etc and these state actually explain which level you are during your deployment. I hope this helps you to understand the time taken during deployment.

Comment: I am glad it is useful for you!! Thanks!!